# Process Maker default tables

Tags: processmaker

I am new to process maker.while I am exploring the process maker I got an employee on boarding process.while understanding the  process I understood the dynaforms but I faced problem with trigger forms. In trigger forms they mentioned tables to get data but i didn't find the tables in my work space. Please let me know if anyone know the answer.
Thanks.

```
@@hrUser = @@USER_LOGGED;

 //Get image
  $sqlSdocument = "SELECT *
  FROM APP_DOCUMENT D, CONTENT C
 WHERE APP_UID = '".@@APPLICATION."'
 AND D.APP_DOC_UID = C.CON_ID
 AND C.CON_CATEGORY = 'APP_DOC_FILENAME'
  ORDER BY APP_DOC_CREATE_DATE DESC";
 $resSdocument = executeQuery($sqlSdocument);
 $dirDocument = $resSdocument[1]['APP_DOC_UID'];
 $httpServer = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
 @@linkImage = 
$httpServer.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/sys".SYS_SYS."/".SYS_LANG."/".SYS_SKIN."
 /cases/cases_ShowDocument?a=".$dirDocument;
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the your code, you want to query the uploaded file but base on the commend, you want to get the image?

Well if employee onboarding is what you want, I am guessing that you uploaded the picture on the first dynaform and you want it to be shown. Well this is your luck because [ProcessMaker Documentation already have that](http://wiki.processmaker.com/3.0/Image_Control#Displaying_uploaded_image_files)

If you want a code that let you see the image immediately after upload, you might want to signup for a enterprise trial and test their Employee Onboarding.